# Lync 2013 external video calls drop after 10 seconds

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I have a Lync 2013 FE and Edge working to provide federated Lync service to our domain. Internal/External chat works fine but when getting on a video call with someone outside of the LAN the call will go through, video and audio, until 10 seconds have passed and the call is dropped. It is consistently 10 seconds every time and I don't know where to start in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I've already seen this. But it could happen for many reasons. Your best bet is to install [Lync Debbuging Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35453) and run `Snooper` to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Thanks for the advice. After enabling logging and looking through them with snooper it became apparent that the internal clients were not allowed UDP 3478 and TCP 443 directly to the edge server.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same and for my environment incoming connections on UDP 3478 and TCP 443 wasn't working due to a temp. block via a firewall feature (aggressive line aging).